How can I modify multi rows in wpDataTables plugin in standard view
How can I modify multi rows in wpDataTables plugin in standard view with php code because the plugin don't offer this option?
i tried to do it in excel view but there is a problem filters hide in this mode and this mode worked only in backend

Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please take the tour
and read how to ask, an On Topic question,
then look at the Question Check list,
the perfect question and
how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example
